# Draggable/Droppable get data/attr from original element when using clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm using jQueryUI draggable/droppable to drag rows from one table to another. I am using `helper: 'clone'` and having a hard time getting any of the data/attributes from the original item that is being dragged. Here is a jsfiddle to better illustrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/e2ter0a4/8/

I am trying to get the `data-id` attribute from the table cell when it is dropped in the droppable area and am unable to do so...

**NOTE:** I am trying to do this through jQueryUI, without having to keep track of the last clicked cell before the drag starts or some other custom solution (I already have a similar workaround implemented just wondering if there was an easier/cleaner solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ui parameter to get it. `ui.draggable` gets the element you are dragging. From the documentation:

> draggable 
>   Type: jQuery 
>   A jQuery object representing the draggable element.

Try this:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui){
    //get data-id from original td
    console.log(ui.draggable[0].getAttribute("data-id"));
  }
});
```

[JQuery UI Droppable documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/)

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2ter0a4/15/)